# There is no data in the request body

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get additional data that is in the body of a request

my code

```
public class TicketController : ReadWriteController<TicketView, Ticket>
{
    public override ReadWriteBusiness<TicketView, Ticket> Business => new TicketBusiness();

    protected override ReadBusiness<TicketView> ReadBusiness => new TicketBusiness();

    public override IActionResult Create([FromBody] Ticket model)
    {
        var message = HttpContext.GetBody().Result;

        return OkJson("ok");
    }    
}
```

and

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PaydarCore.Api;

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static async Task<string> GetBody(this HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        httpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
        httpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        var rawRequestBody = await new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        return rawRequestBody;
    }
}
```

my model

```
public class Ticket : Entity
{
    public Ticket()
    {
        RelatedItems = new ExpandoObject();
    }

    public override long Id { get; set; }

    public int TicketNumber { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public long? TicketDepartmentId { get; set; }

    public long TicketPriorityId { get; set; }

    public long TicketStateId { get; set; }
}
```

my body request

```
{
    "ticketNumber" : 12,
    "subject" :"",
    "ticketPriorityId":1,
    "ticketStateId": 1,
    "message":"fjhsdkfhjsdfhkjsdhf"
}
```

My goal is to get the value "message" in request body

That this property does not exist in my model

But there is no value in the body

I found by testing that removing the FromBody puts the value in the body

How can I get the body value?

----edit---
I noticed that by adding this code to Startup the problem is solved. Is there another way?

```
 app.Use(next => context =>
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();
            return next(context);
        });
```

Comment: why have you not defined `message` property in the `Ticket` class?

Comment: @letsdoit   message property  in There is another model that must be saved in the database with the ticket ID after adding the ticket in the database.

Comment: but is there any harm in adding `message` to the `Ticket` class? and access it simply like `model.message`?

Comment: If using `EnableBuffering` is working, that suggests your request body is being read multiple times. This is a really peculiar way to read the body though, why are you not just letting the framework deserialise for you? Also, you should not be using `Task.Result` ever, instead make the method `async` and `await` it.